# How would I be able to connect to SQLAlchemy python to a server.py file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

What I want to do is have a file called **server.py** that has the SQLAlchemy database in it and a web server file called **webServer.py** that has all the redirecting and button click events in it. I don't know how to connect the two. The database works when the **server.py** code in inside the **webServer.py** file, I have all the imports, just in case anyone needs the code, here it is:

**webServer.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import redirect, url_for, request, session
from server import *

web_server = Flask(__name__)
web_server.secret_key = "SecretKey"

""" ROUTING """


@web_server.route("/")
@web_server.route("/home")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@web_server.route("/sign-in", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def signIn():
    if request.method == "POST":
        uip = request.form["UIP"]
        pip = request.form["PIP"]

        # START PF DATABASE TESTING

        isAcct = checkForAccount(uip)
        if isAcct:
            isCorrect = checkUser(uip, pip)
            if isCorrect:
                print("CORRECT")
                return redirect(url_for("index"))
            else:
                print("FALSE")
                return render_template("signIn.html", incorrectPass="Wrong username or password.")
        else:
            createAccount(uip, pip)
            return render_template("signIn.html")

        # END OF DATABASE TESTING
    else:
        return render_template("signIn.html")


@web_server.route("/run<data>")
def run(data):
    check = checkUser()
    if check:
        print(data)
    return "none"


""" ERROR HANDLING """

@web_server.errorhandler(404)
def error404(error):
    return render_template("error.html", EC="Error! Page Not Found!"), 404


@web_server.errorhandler(500)
def error500(error):
    return render_template("error.html", EC="Error! Internal Server Issue!"), 500


print("Server Loaded..")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    # server.run(host="192.168.1.80", port="3000") #For running on IP address
    web_server.run(port="3000")
```

**server.py**

```
from webServer import web_server
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

web_server.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///dataBase.sqlite3"
web_server.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(web_server)

class dataBase(db.Model):
    #_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

def checkUser(username, password):
    usernameQuery = dataBase.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    correctUser = usernameQuery.username
    correctPass = usernameQuery.password

    if username == correctUser and password == correctPass:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def checkForAccount(uip):
    found_user = dataBase.query.filter_by(username=uip).first()
    return found_user

def createAccount(uip, pip):
    accountStartupData = dataBase(uip, pip)
    db.session.add(accountStartupData)
    db.session.commit()
```

**And here is the error:**

> [2020-05-18 17:59:48,172] ERROR in app: Exception on /sign-in [POST]
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_collections.py",
>   line 1020, in **call**
>       return self.registry[key] KeyError: 15864
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 2447, in wsgi_app
>       response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1821, in handle_user_exception
>       reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
>   line 39, in reraise
>       raise value   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
>       rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
>   line 1936, in dispatch_request
>       return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "C:/Users/callu/Documents/Javo/webServer.py", line 25, in signIn
>       isAcct = checkForAccount(uip)   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\server.py", line 30, in checkForAccount
>       found_user = dataBase.query.filter_by(username=uip).first()   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy__init__.py",
>   line 519, in **get**
>       return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py",
>   line 78, in **call**
>       return self.registry()   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_collections.py",
>   line 1022, in **call**
>       return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py",
>   line 3286, in **call**
>       return self.class_(**local_kw)   File "C:\Users\callu\Documents\Javo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy__init__.py",
>   line 137, in **init**
>       track_modifications = app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] KeyError: 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'